# Rewriting a common function using tail-end recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp, racket, tail-recursion

I've been trying to tinker with this code to rewrite a "repeat" function using tail-end recursion but have gotten a bit stuck in my attempts.

```
(define (repeat n x)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons x (repeat (- n 1) x))))
```

This is the original "repeat" function.  It traverses through 'n - 1' levels of recursion then appends 'x' into a list in 'n' additional recursive calls.  Instead of that, the recursive call should be made and the 'x' should be appended to a list at the same time.

```
(define (repeat-tco n x)
  (trace-let rec ([i 0]
                  [acc '()])
    (if (= i n)
        acc
        (rec (+ i 1) (cons x acc)))))
```

This is the closest rewritten version that I've come up with which I believe follows tail-call recursion but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: The syntactically recursive `rec` call is "in tail position" - you could see the difference by running with `(trace-define (repeat ... `. (It would be more consistent in repeat-tco to write `(let rec ([n n]) ...` and `(= n 0)` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `repeat-tco` function is indeed tail recursive: it is so because the recursive call to `rec` is in 'tail position': at the point where it's called, the function that is calling it has nothing left to do but return the value of that call.

[The following is just some perhaps useful things: the answer is above, but an answer which was essentially 'yes' seemed too short.]

This trick of taking a procedure `p` which accumulates some result via, say `(cons ... (p ...))` and turning it into a procedure with an extra 'accumulator' argument which is then tail recursive is very common.  A result of using this technique is that the results come out backwards: this doesn't matter for you because all the elements of your list are the same, but imagine this:

```
(define (evens/backwards l)
  (let loop ([lt l]
             [es '()])
    (if (null? lt)
        es
        (loop (rest lt)
              (if (even? (first lt))
                  (cons (first lt) es)
                  es)))))
```

This will return the even elements of its arguments, but backwards.  If you want them the right way around, a *terrible* answer is

```
(define (evens/terrible l)
  (let loop ([lt l]
             [es '()])
    (if (null? lt)
        es
        (loop (rest lt)
              (if (even? (first lt))
                  (append es (list (first lt)))
                  es)))))
```

(Why is it a terrible answer?)  The proper answer is

```
(define (evens l)
  (let loop ([lt l]
             [es '()])
    (if (null? lt)
        (reverse es)
        (loop (rest lt)
              (if (even? (first lt))
                  (cons (first lt) es)
                  es)))))
```